# How to fix this blank page drupal issue.I am getting blank content

Tags: drupal

[image][image]

When i click on add user add field or any contents i am getting my page as blank
I have searched everywhere but not able to recover

Comment: Impossible to answer the question like this.
Any bad module or theme change could cause this.

Comment: As Pascal says, any module can cause this. Try turning off modules one by one and see will that still happen.

Comment: in module file also i am getting this screen

Comment: Please use drush if you are not able to access pages from the admin, turn modules off by running `drush dis <modulename>`  
turn modules on by running `drush en <modulename>`. 
Also try looking in recent log messages in `yoururl/admin/reports/dblog`
there might be vital clues as to where the site has broken. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove modules one by one. You will get the solution

try drush code from command line

```
drush pm-unistall <modulename>
```

To get list of all modules use command

```
drush pm-list --type=module --status=enabled
```

Hope this will help